# How to choose lightweight Gems for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails and I have a problem choosing right gems for my app. As an example, now I need a gem to make slugs for links. I found a lot of them here https://www.ruby-toolbox.com. But the most popular gems are doing +10 things I will never use. And this happens with all most popular Gems.

Is there a smart way to choose lightweight Gems for Rails? Maybe there is a way to see how much code has the Gem in github? Or how many files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a really nice guide on choosing a gem: [Exploring RubyGems](http://railscasts.com/episodes/384-exploring-rubygems)

And here is how Ryan suggests to count lines in a gem:

1. clone gem repo
2. use cloc command to count lines

Example:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git
$ cloc app lib
      87 text files.
      86 unique files.                              
      23 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.56  T=1.0 s (64.0 files/s, 5294.0 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ruby                            64            762           1513           3019
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                            64            762           1513           3019
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can also check line counts in `test` or `spec` directories to check test coverage.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would wonder if a gem is actually necessary if the gem only has limited functionality. Why not just build slugs for links yourself? It's hardly worth using a gem for.

On the other hand, usually you can customize gems as you please. For example, devise contains a lot of functionality you might not need. In this gem, you can simply choose to use only the part you actually need. Besides, you can customize all you want.

Checking the github of popular gems can be an important first step. It can give you insight in what the gem actually does and what code it contains. If it's too big for your taste, you could even consider to use only parts of the provided code. For example, you could copy-paste the github code (instead of requiring the gem in your gemfile) and comment out the code that is irrelevant to your case, altough it's not something I would personally recommend.

Comment: Thanks, I needed these thoughts to be sure about my decisions choosing right gems!